# Java, Lucene : Get document by saved Id and then update one of it's field

Tags: java, lucene

We are creating a Spring-MVC application in which we are using Lucene for text indexing and searching. I am saving the Object's ID along with it for retrieving the associated Java Object later. How do I get the Document with saved ID and update a field which is being set manually. I know how to search for given text, but nothing specific for a single document. Thank you.

Save code :

```
// retrieve from the ID below
            doc.add(new StringField("id", String.valueOf(objectId), Field.Store.YES));
// Update the Integer count below
 LegacyIntField intField = new LegacyIntField("score",0,Field.Store.YES);
                    intField.setIntValue(1);
                    doc.add(intField);
```

Current update code :

```
 Path path = Paths.get(OUR_PATH);
                    Directory index_dir = FSDirectory.open(path);

                    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(index_dir, new IndexWriterConfig(new StandardAnalyzer()));
                    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(writer);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all lucene does not support updating a single field and thus there's no benefit in trying to isolate and optimize the update process of a single field.

Basically what you are looking for is a way to:

- load the original document that was previously indexed (this is not provided out of the box with lucene)
- and a method to update an existing document (this is [IndexWriter.updateDocument](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#updateDocument-org.apache.lucene.index.Term-java.lang.Iterable-))

If the lucene index is not the primary datastore you should use your primary datastore to fetch the document set the new vaue and then reindex the whole document, in pseudo code:

```
public void updateField(String docId, int newFieldvalue) {
    MyDataObject data = primaryDataStore.fetch(docId);
    data.setFieldValue(newFieldValue);
    primaryDataStore.save(data);
    updateIndex(data);
}

public void updateIndex(MyDataObject object) {
    // convertToLucene is more or less the code in the
    // first snippet of your question 
    Document d = convertToLucene(object);
    // IndexWriter should be created once
    // IndexWriter.updateDocument will internally delete and index 
    // the document
    this.writer.updateDocument(new Term("id", object.getId()), d);
    // potentially call writer.commit()
}
```

If lucene is your primary datastore it's more complex and I strongly suggest (if not too late) to use solr or elasticsearch which provides a nice REST API that makes lucene more like a document store.
You have to consider that lucene is not "out of the box" a document datastore. If you want to use lucene as a primary datastore what you could do is store the document in a stored field using a format of your choice (JSON, binary serialization,...).

To fetch the document you'll have to perform a search query on the field "id" you created with a TermQuery, use a collector or TodDocs and then call document(int luceneDocId) on `IndexReader` or `IndexSearcher` to fetch stored fields, in pseudo code (methods to replace `primaryDataStore.fetch(docId)` used in the previous snippet):

```
public MyDataObject fetchFromLucene(String docId) {
     IndexSearcher searcher = getSearcher();
     TopDocs docs = searcher.search(new TermQuery(new Term("id", docId)), 1);
     if (docs.totalHits > 0) {
         Document d = searcher.document(docs.scoreDocs[0].doc);
         // "document_data" is a binary field you'll have to add
         // on every lucene docs where you put a serialized version
         // of your domain object.
         return deserialize( d.getBinaryValue("document_data") );
     }
     return null;
}

public MyDataObject deserialize(ByteRef data) {
    // a method to deserialize binary data into MyDataObject
    return deserializedData;
}
```

In short you'll end up writing a lot of boiler plate code if you want to deal with lucene directly as a primary datastore.
Note that you'll have to manage yourself a lot of lowlevel lucene aspects such as refreshing your IndexReaders in a way that is efficient.