# When I created Lucene index, Can I set document ID in order to overwrite the same document by the same Id

Tags: lucene

I have many documents need to be indexed by Lucene, there are duplicated documents(I can't delete them because they comes on fly), So I'm thinking that can Lucene overwrite the same document by same document Id, when I choose the option Store.YES.
I have to store the document, also there are many many duplicated documents, it occupys a lot of space, I really need the auto overwrite function. I know ElasticSearch have this function.

Comment: Use [IndexWriter.html#updateDocument](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_4_2/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#updateDocument(org.apache.lucene.index.Term,java.lang.Iterable)). that will first delete all indexed documents (if any) which match the provided term, and then it will add the new document. In your case, the term will be the document ID you mention in the question.

Comment: Related (for an example showing `updateDocument`): [Get document by saved Id and then update one of it's field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44904777/java-lucene-get-document-by-saved-id-and-then-update-one-of-its-field/44909121#44909121)